# how to save the results of XPathSelectElements to xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file and I wanna extract some elements using XPathSelectElements("..."). It works fine but I have no idea how to save the extracted data into a new XML file with a new outer wrap

Here's what I've got, XPathSelectElements works fine:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("XXX.xml");
var nData = doc.XPathSelectElements("Orders/Order[@ID > 1]");

//code to save data to a new file...
```

My original xml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Orders>
  <Order ID="1">aaa</Order>
  <Order ID="2">bbb</Order>
  <Order ID="3">ccc</Order>
</Orders>
```

And I wanna save the result to a new xml file and with an extra wrap like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<newWrap>
 <Orders>
   <Order ID="2">bbb</Order>
   <Order ID="3">ccc</Order>
 </Orders>
</newWrap>
```

Any help? Thanks a lot~

Comment: As an aside, unless you have a particular reason to use XPath then the LINQ to XML query methods are often a better option as it's statically typed.  For example, `doc.Elements("Orders").Elements("Order").Where(o => (int)o.Attribute("ID") > 1)` would achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
var nData = doc.XPathSelectElements("Orders/Order[@ID > 1]");
var root = new XElement("newWrap", 
                    new XElement("Orders", nData)
            );
var newDoc = new XDocument(root);
newDoc.Save("new_file.xml");
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/stCUy0)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks ~ that's exactly what I want